# Exact opposite to Ruby's CGI.parse method?

Tags: ruby, cgi

I'd like to do some sanitization of query params.

I parse the query with `CGI.parse`, then I delete some params, but I can't find an opposite method to build the query.

I don't really want to do something like

```
params.map{|n,v| "#{CGI.escape n}=#{CGI.escape v.to_s}"}.join("&")
```

There's got to be a simpler way. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no better answer, I'll put up the method which I'm using now.

```
def build_query(params)
  params.map do |name,values|
    values.map do |value|
      "#{CGI.escape name}=#{CGI.escape value}"
    end
  end.flatten.join("&")
end
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a nice method in URI module:

```
require 'uri'
URI.encode_www_form("q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en")  #=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Rails (or don't mind pulling in ActiveSupport), then you can use [`to_param` (AKA `to_query`)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_param):

```
{ :a => '&', :b => 'Where is pancake house?', :c => ['an', 'array'] }.to_param
# a=%26&b=Where+is+pancake+house%3F&c%5B%5D=an&c%5B%5D=array
```

`to_param` handles arrays a little differently than your version though, it'll put out `c[]=an&c[]=array` rather than just `c=an&c=array`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following is a simplification, but it avoids expanding the (key, value) pairs of a hash.

```
params.map{|qq| qq.map{|q| CGI.escape(q)}.join('=')}.join('&')
```